# How i can integrate 3rd party tax engine in magento2?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, taxes

I have a 3rd party tax engine and i want to create a module in Magento2 that collect the data that the tax engine need(ie shipping address, amount, etc). and send it to the tax engine. This is the easy part for me..however the hard part, or at least the part that i can not understand fully is the integration part, i mean; how Magento works regarding the integration of third-party tax calculation engines, should i implement some kind of interface in my Magento module in order to Magento can be able to recognize it as a tax calculation module?

Thanks!!

Comment: @AnkitShah Web API is not relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

These are the interfaces of the tax module: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/Tax/Api

**In theory** you just have to implement them and use DI preferences to replace the core implementations (see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html)

**In practice** this might not work as expected because the service contracts (i.e. the "Api" interfaces) are not matured enough yet and Magento often relies on implementation details of the core implementations.